# Changing font in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, visual-c#-express-2010

I am using this code to make all my textboxes the same font:

```
          if (textBox1.Font.Underline)
        {
            foreach (Control y in this.Controls)
            {
                if (y is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(y)).Font = new Font(((TextBox)(y)).Font, FontStyle.Regular);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (Control y in this.Controls)
            {
                if (y is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)(y)).Font = new Font(((TextBox)(y)).Font, FontStyle.Underline);
                }
            }
```

Lets say i click the bold button. The text will turn Bold. When i click the underline button, the text should be Bold and underlined, but it is only underlined??? WHY?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`FontStyle` is an enumeration you can `Or` them together to add or `Xor` to remove.

i.e.

to add underlining to existing style:

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
```

to remove underlining from style:

```
textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
```

and you can check for which Enumerations are in the Font.Style by doing this.

```
if ((textBox1.Font.Style.HasFlag(FontStyle.Underline)))
{
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
}
else
{
    textBox1.Font = new Font(textBox1.Font, textBox1.Font.Style | FontStyle.Underline);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try using something like this

```
  List<Control> controls = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().Cast<Control>().ToList();
  foreach (Control m in controls)
  {
      if (m.Font.Bold)
      {
          m.Font = new Font(m.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
      }
      else
      {
           m.Font = new Font(m.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
           m.Font = new Font(m.Font, FontStyle.Underline);
      }

  }
```

Comment: it still does the same thing. I need it to add the style. Like if i have it bold, and i click underline, i want it Bold and Underline.

Comment: keep in mind i have a underline button, a **bold** button, and a _italic_ button

Comment: @Elite Gamer well all you have to do is to use the if statements like above determine what style the textbox is and based on this style what style you want

Comment: @Elite Gamer look at above example i check if the text is bold I add underline

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
((TextBox)(y)).Font = new Font(((TextBox)(y)).Font, FontStyle.Underline);
```

use

```
((TextBox)(y)).Font = new Font(((TextBox)(y)).Font.FontFamily, ((TextBox)(y)).Font.Size, FontStyle.Underline);
```