# How to preserve current font/style while making changes to RTF text in C# Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, richtextbox, rtf, treelist

Using Visual Studio to create a Windows Forms application, using C#.
I have a RichTextBox. This box supports formatting like colours, bold, and underline.

I've added buttons such that people can format their text right in the box.
For example, the Bold button does this:

```
if (!message.SelectionFont.Bold)
    message.SelectionFont = new Font(message.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
else
    message.SelectionFont = new Font(message.Font, FontStyle.Regular);
```

This works fine for bolding and unbolding regular text. The issue is when it is combined with other formatting. The creation of a new Font wipes away the original formatting, and leaves me with pure bold or pure regular text.

How can I preserve original formatting, while changing text to bold?

It shouldn't be hard-coded. I shouldn't be checking if(bold), if(italics), if(underline) for every option, as ideally I'll be adding more options later (colour, font, font size, etc).

Comment: but you already answered on your question.. have a function which will create a combined `Font` depending on currently set options (bold, italic, size, etc) and simply apply it to selection. It will works whenever you press or un-press either of your font style buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

This link might be of interest:
[How do I maintain RichText formatting (bold/italic/etc) when changing any one element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325918/how-do-i-maintain-richtext-formatting-bold-italic-etc-when-changing-any-one-el)

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove properties to the enumeration FontStyle as was answered here.

[Changing font in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11279224/changing-font-in-c)